# Automatically scroll jqgrid after data is loaded

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am loading a jqgrid with approximately 100 rows of data. When the data is finished loading into the jqgrid, I would like to automatically scroll the jqgrid so that a certain row is at the top. The top row will depend on the loaded data (ex: the first row that contains the value "1" in the 3rd column, etc). Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution using gridComplete

```
gridComplete: function() {
    var ids = jQuery("#my_jqgrid").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++)
    {
      var current_id = ids[i];
      var row_data = $("#my_jqgrid").getRowData(current_id);
      if(row_data['status'] == '1')
      {
        var height = $("#"+current_id).attr('offsetHeight');
        var index = $("#dynamic_arrival_times").getInd(current_id);
        $(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").scrollTop(height*index);
        return;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

The cleanest way is doing this:

```
gridComplete: function() {
   $("#"+$('#GRID').jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow')).focus();
}
```

Comment: This solution works well. I also added a "$('selector').effect('highlight')" to put emphasis on the row the user just modified.

Answer (score 1):

```
gridComplete: function() {
    var gridScroll = $('div.ui-jqgrid-bdiv'); 
    gridScroll.scrollTop(gridScroll[0].scrollHeight - gridScroll.height());
}
```

Comment: you could use $('#grid_id').closest('div.ui-jqgrid-bdiv'), which returns the div container of your table, and probably this way is more efficient when traversing the dom